# Reset PIN window disappear when typing on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I need to reset my Windows 11 PIN code because I forgot it.

For this I go to Settings > Accounts > Security options > PIN.
Then I choose the "I forgot my PIN" option, not the "Modify PIN" which asks for the current PIN.

At this point I am presented with a window with some information, I click on Continue and I first need to put my Windows password.
But randomly (i.e. 3, 5, 8 characters or just moving the mouse), when I type the password, the window disappears...

I tried another option of typing my password somewhere, copy and paste it in the password field in the window but it seems to paste the copied text twice.

The whole thing seems very buggy and frustrating.

Do you have any idea what is happening and where does this behaviour come from?

I am a Mac user, I am not sure where to look, maybe accessibility settings, known bugs, other workarounds. The problem only appears on this specific window.

For information, Windows 11 is fully up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost for sure you have a Microsoft Account.

Log in here:

https://account.microsoft.com/account/manage-my-account

And use the Forgot Password routine to reset your Password and PIN.

This has worked for me.

Comment: It worked obviously. Still curious about the window behaviour.

Comment: This is how Microsoft implemented their Microsoft Accounts.

Comment: I doubt they intended to make the window disappear before you have time to enter your password.

Comment: That is probably correct. My comment was more toward what does one do if this situation occurs and that is to recover via the Account login